# login prompt box in a secure mode

Tags: c#, powershell

Is it possible to make a secure login prompt box (powershell or C#) as windows ask in a UAC prompt window for username and password and you can't minimize it until you write your creds in a field.

The following is a simple ps1 script to ask for creds but can't it be done in a secure way you know forcing the user's to provide the creds and lock all other windows like a UAC login prompt.

I know it can be done by `$form.TopMost = $True` but I don't want this property.

```
[int]$cnt = 1
while ( $cnt -lt '1000000000' ) {

    $user    = [Environment]::UserName
    $domain  = [Environment]::UserDomainName

    $credentials = $Host.UI.PromptForCredential('windows update','',$user,[Environment]::UserDomainName)
    $pass = $credentials.getnetworkcredential().password

    Add-Type -assemblyname system.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement 
    $localMachine = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext([System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType]::Machine)
    $credtest = $localMachine.ValidateCredentials($user,$pass)


    if ( $credtest -eq $false ) {

    Add-Type -assemblyname System.Windows.Forms
    $choice = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Authentication failed! Please enter correct password", "Reconnection Attempt Failed!", [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK, [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Warning)     
    } 

else { 

    break 
    }

    $cnt++
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The UAC prompt isn't simply 'locking all other windows' - it is actually displayed on a different desktop where no other user code can run.  This prevents a malicious script/app from sending Window messages to the prompt that might, say, accept the prompt against the user's wishes.

It is possible to force UAC to [use the user's normal desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/user-account-control/user-account-control-group-policy-and-registry-key-settings#user-account-control-switch-to-the-secure-desktop-when-prompting-for-elevation), but this is less secure than the default setting and is usually only used when there are issues with graphics due to switching.

So, while you might be able to 'lock out' other windows in your custom logon prompt, it won't be a 'secure login prompt box' in the same way UAC is as it is missing the critical element of desktop switching.